# How can I stop the movement of the nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j, relationship, nodes, graph-databases

I'm using Neo4j with webadmin interface.

When I run a query I display the nodes and relationships graphically. 
However, whenever I move a node, the other nodes connected to it move too.
How can I stop this "*force-attraction*" effect?

Thank you very much

Comment: When I export the graph as a PNG for example, it stops the movement of the nodes.

Comment: The "export PNG" option works for me, but is a disaster for large graphs. So sad that you still can't turn off this confusing animation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to turn off this behaviour specifically within the browser although when you manually move a node, it becomes "pinned" to that location so will then not move when its neighbours do.

If you think you would find more control over the node movements useful, you could always raise an issue or pull request on GitHub.